# Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

**Context:**

I'm currently weighing options on project for social media management.
We are currently considering custom build vs product based approach.
The requirements:

- Manage content publishing to Facebook (wall post, event) and Twitter.
- plan (workflow & approval process) & schedule the content publishing with a team (manager, seeder, etc)
- Listening to conversation stream on the account profiles being managed
- Engaging with fans and follower to identify influence and lead.
- Performance analytic on the social media campaign

Since this is salesforce group, so obvious it's Salesforce Marketing Cloud which consist of Radian6 & Buddy Media (and Social.com).

**Questions:**

- Which marketing cloud component do I need? My research tells me I just need the Buddy Media.

Thank you.

Note: I can't create the right tags for this topic since my reputation still low, so chose a generic one.

Comment: Welcome to salesforce.stsckexchange. The site aims to have content snd questions which can result in correct, non subjective answers. Currently your question(s),are broad and may get this post closed. My suggestion would be to keep only the middle question. You can find reviews and blogs online to answer your first, and you will need to contact salesforce for any pricing info.

Comment: just want to add some info i gained from the salesforce rep, buddy media is packaging by how many social accounts you wanna manage. So the more accounts you manage, your cost increases as well. This doesn't work out for marketing agencies such as my company. Other similar product is the better choice to manage many accounts. FYI basic package is approx US$55k/year (3 social accounts) with $975 per extra account.

Answer (score 2):

While I don't have direct experience in using these products, I've sat through multiple demos of the tools. I agree that to publish your content to Facebook and Twitter, Buddy Media is the right tool. For listening and responding to conversations and monitoring what people are saying about you, Radian 6 is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, from the demos i watched I observe that Buddy Media also has some capabilities to listen to conversation streams and also respond to. I know Salesforce is marketing Radian6 for listening tool. So I've kinda blur on the distinction between the two for listening capability.